# if action can occur at any stage of the activity diagram,how to show it?

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram

If at any stage of the activity diagram, the user could click on “Cancel” to finish operation, how shown should be displayed?

Comment: Well you could draw a line everytime an activity can redirect to logout or you could give the logout activity an identifier like a number and then include that identifier in the other activities, you just have to put a note describing your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an interruptible region. The entire process is an interruptible region and the click on cancel is the interrupting event.

To see how to draw such a region, see for example [here](http://www.zicomi.com/interruptibleActivityRegion.jsp)

Comment: thanks for your help,i have 3 partition in this diagram,should i set all partition in a interrupt region?

Comment: To my knowledge, unfortunately, partitions and regions are difficult to use together. If your tool allows it, you might try to put your partitions inside your region, but normally, an activity node should be in a partition, not the other way around.

A solution might be to put in the interruptible region only the interrupting event and a single action pointing to another diagram with your partitions and your real content.